# I need to be able to add but there is an error. SYNTAX ERROR INSERT INTO and cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

Tags: vb.net

```
    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        'open connection if it is not yet open
        cnn.Open()
    End If

    cmd.Connection = cnn
    'check whether add new or update
    If Me.txtcheckID.Tag & "" = "" Then
        'add new 
        'add data to table
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO student(checkid, branch, amount, type, status, date, address) " & _
                        " VALUES(" & Me.txtcheckID.Text & ",'" & Me.txtBranch.Text & "','" & _
                        Me.cboType.Text & "','" & Me.txtStatus.Text & "','" & _
                        Me.txtAddress.Text & "','" & Me.txtDate.Text & "','" & Me.txtAmount.Text & "')"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Else
        'update data in table
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE student " & _
                    " SET checkid=" & Me.txtcheckID.Text & _
                    ", branch='" & Me.txtBranch.Text & "'" & _
                    ", type='" & Me.cboType.Text & "'" & _
                    ", status='" & Me.txtStatus.Text & "'" & _
                    ", address='" & Me.txtAddress.Text & "'" & _
                    ", amount='" & Me.txtAmount.Text & "'" & _
                    ", date='" & Me.txtDate.Text & "'" & _
                    " WHERE checkid=" & Me.txtcheckID.Tag
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End If
    'refresh data in list
    RefreshData()
    'clear form
    Me.btnClear.PerformClick()

    'close connection
    cnn.Close()
```

Comment: Use parametrized queries. Sticking input directly into a query opens you up to SQL injection and mysterious bugs. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6bdf8b71-1cf1-41c0-848c-4fca2c9e1ea2/faq-how-do-i-make-a-parameterized-query-in-the-database-with-vbnet?forum=vbgeneral

Comment: how can i resolve this error/debug?

Comment: Start by using parametrized queries. The problem might solve itself when you do that. If it doesn’t, it will be more obvious and I will also be happy to help then if you still can’t find it.

Comment: As suggested, you really should use parameterised queries. It helps avoid issues like this but, most importantly, it improves security. That said, if you want to know what's wrong with your SQL then you have to actually look at your SQL and not just the code that constructs it. Have you looked at the actual value of `cmd.CommandText`?

Comment: I'm also going to suggest and stress **[parameterized queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx)**. And for debugging/learning/fun (only!): print your query (after all the 'variables' have been put in ofcourse)! Copy/paste it into SQL Management Studio if you need to and run/analyze it. Chances are there's an `'` in one of your 'variables' somewhere or something similar that 'breaks' your query.

Comment: what is the possible way to solve this issue? Will you help to fix this code sir?

Comment: A good start would be to stop ignoring the advice you get in comments and apply it instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO student(checkid, branch, amount, type, status, date, address) " & _
                    " VALUES(" & Me.txtcheckID.Text & ",'" & Me.txtBranch.Text & "','" & _
                    Me.cboType.Text & "','" & Me.txtStatus.Text & "','" & _
                    Me.txtAddress.Text & "','" & Me.txtDate.Text & "','" & Me.txtAmount.Text & "')"
```

Sorry if I'm being stupid, but would having 2 spaces in the CommandText string between address) and VALUES where the first line break is cause in error? Not sure how VB and OleDB handles whitespace and my account is too new to comment...

Comment: No. Whitespace is not relevant in a query (unless in literals ofcourse...)

Comment: Oh ok, I did some quick Googling but couldn't find something that said one way or the other so I figured I'd bring it up.